# is there any way to add period task dynamically at run time in celery?

Tags: flask, celery

Celery has documentation about [Periodic Task](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#:%7E:text=celery%20beat%20is%20a%20scheduler,entries%20in%20a%20SQL%20database.), it has shown couple of example how can we add period task. For example:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery()

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Calls test('hello') every 10 seconds.
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, test.s('hello'), name='add every 10')
```

This will set periodic task at initialization. However, I would like to add period task based user's activity e.g. when user visit task page in Flask view. I have flask view like:

```
@app.route('/task', methods=['GET'])
def payload_mobile_android():
    return {'task': 'mytask'}, 200
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? If so, please share it.

Comment: Yes, you have to build custom schedular. Take look this app for reference https://github.com/zmap/celerybeat-mongo